# How do I change button color in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

How can I change button color when it is clicked? I tried the :active style but it don't work on the android device (however it does work in the browser).

For example I have a button like this

```
<button class="button button-full button-calm button-login" type="submit">Sign In</button>
```

and styles like this

```
.login .button-login {
  width:96%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  moz-border-radius: 4px;
  webkit-border-radius: 4px;    
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.login .button-login:active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

I expect the button to become yellow when I touch it and become red back when the user lift the finger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, nice idea will be to replace `<button>` with a carefully styled `<a>`.

For example like this.

```css
#button {
    background-color: #E3E1B8; 
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font: 13px sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-color: #aaa #444 #444 #aaa;
    color: #000
}

#button:hover { background-color: #46000D; }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button">New Element</a>
```

Comment: @AnhTuan it will be harder to style your button as ionic, but I hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

```
        I have done it using Ionic Way what he has done in own css.

 <button id="login2-button9" class="button button-gold">English</button>
```

Add this in your css file

```
      .button.button-gold {
            border-color: transparent;
            background-color: #625031;
            color: #000000; }
            .button.button-gold:hover {
              color: #000000;
              text-decoration: none; }
            .button.button-gold.active, .button.button-gold.activated {
              background-color:#c0a062; }
            .button.button-gold.button-clear {
              border-color: transparent;
              background: none;
              box-shadow: none;
              color: #625031; }
            .button.button-gold.button-icon {
              border-color: transparent;
              background: none; }
            .button.button-gold.button-outline {
              border-color: #625031;
              background: transparent;
              color: #625031; }
              .button.button-gold.button-outline.active, .button.button-gold.button-outline.activated {
                background-color: #625031;
                box-shadow: none;
                color: #000000; }
```