# Change button when push it

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to change background and colour of my button when push it, I have read that it's using .active .activated so... Somebody can send me one example using that please?
Thank you very much.

Best regards!

Comment: Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918745/how-do-i-change-button-color-in-ionic-framework). Similar problem solved for on mouse hover action

Comment: gvlachakis thanks for reply me. I have read the post and Im try like this:
In my html:
 <button class="button button-example"> 
        <img src="/build/img/icono_frio.png" > 
  </button>
In my scss:
.button.button-example {

    .button.button-example.active {
        background-color:#c0a062; 
    }
    
    .button.button-example.activated {
        background-color:#d2392b;
    }     
}

But doesnt work. You know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a style rule like this one:

```
button.activated {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

And should work fine. [Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Or0fy?p=preview).

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! You've helped me:) but in this case when you push the button, it changes the colour and it stays fixed. I will need that it change the colour only when you have kept the button, and return to initial color when released. I dont know if I've explained...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yeahhhhh!! haha works fine! :D and last question :S if I only have change the colour for only one button (not all buttons) how is the solution? Thanks again!!

Comment: Add a class to that button only `<button class="custom">...</button>` and the rule would be `button.custom.activated{ ... }`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you ;)

Comment: sebaferreras, can you put again the your first example please? The example was change the colour when you push the button and it stays fixed. Thanks in advance!!